# VS2013 Sharepoint Configuration Wizard not loading any lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently working on a SP2013 dev environment and yesterday had to restart the server. After restarting I re-opened the project I was working on and when I tried creating a new workflow to associate with a list (using SP Customization Wizard) on the site nothing was loading. The site I'm deploying to is up and I'm able to deploy the app. It's just nothing loads on the SP Customization Wizard.

Has anyone encountered this before? I've tried restarting SP server and VS2013 to no avail.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever resolve this issue?